# Using Mathematica in Vim produces errors when printing in TeXForm (double backslash, " b'-/n' ")

Tags: plugin-ultisnips, plugin-vimtex

I've been trying to integrate Mathematica with my Vimtex set-up, inspired by this article: https://castel.dev/post/lecture-notes-1/ The basic idea is to use UltiSnips to run an operation in Wolfram Script without leaving Vim, for quick computations. I've been having some issues with printing the result in TeXForm, though.

I have the following in my UltiSnips: (essentially same as the article)

```
priority 10
snippet math "mathematica block" i
math $1 math$0
endsnippet

priority 100
snippet 'math(.*)math' "evaluate mathematica" wr
`!p
import subprocess
code = 'ToString[' + match.group(1) + ', TeXForm]'
snip.rv = subprocess.check_output(['wolframscript', '-code', code])
`
endsnippet
```

However, when I run an operation, I have some serious issues. All the backslashes \ are doubled (so \frac{1}{2} turns into \\frac{1}{2}), and the entire output is wrapped in b' and \n'

For example,

```
math 1+1 math
```

expands to

```
b'2\n'
```

and

```
math Roots[x^2-1/2 == 0, x] math
```

expands to

```
b'x=\\frac{1}{\\sqrt{2}}\\lor x=-\\frac{1}{\\sqrt{2}}\n'
```

I've fixed this temporarily by defining the b' - \n' as a text object, then recording an operation that deletes the text object and replaces all "\\" with "\". However, I really don't like this solution, and I feel like there's probably more issues that I haven't run into yet since I haven't used this setup for very long.

Any ideas?

Comment: This sounds like a python bytes-string issue. Curious

Answer (score 2):

I do not know whether you have found a solution in the mean time, but
according to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-string
you have to decode the bytes object, so that the snippet becomes:

```
snippet 'math(.*)math' "math" wr
`!p
import subprocess
code = match.group(1)
code = 'ToString[' + code + ',TeXForm]'
res = subprocess.check_output(['wolframscript', '-code', code])
snip.rv=res.decode('utf-8')
`
endsnippet
```

by the way thank you for the very cool ideas you posted on https://castel.dev/post/lecture-notes-1/